# Data Transfer Failure between Angular and Vue2 through Web Component

Tags: angular, vue.js, web-component

Due to necessary reasons, I must introduce a web component created by Vue2 within Angular. We've gone through quite a lot of difficulties, and the current problem is that I can't pass data to Vue's web component through properties. To be precise, I can't "smoothly" send it. If I pass the data through hardcoding, it can succeed, but there is almost no practicality to speak of. Below, I'll demonstrate the current situation:

**Vue part**

> main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import vueCustomElement from 'vue-custom-element';

Vue.use(vueCustomElement);
Vue.customElement('my-vue-component', App, {
  props: ['test']
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

> App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <ul class="top-menu">
      <li @click="currentView = 'home'">index</li>
      <li @click="currentView = 'my-component'">show my-component</li>
    </ul>
    <p>from angular's value {{ test }}</p>
    <component :is="currentComponent.component" v-bind="currentComponent.props" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    'home' : HelloWorld,
    'my-component': MyComponent,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      currentView: 'home',
    };
  },
  computed: {
    currentComponent() {
      return {
        component: this.currentView === 'home' ? 'home' : 'my-component',
        props: { msg: this.currentView === 'home' ? 'open vue index' : '' }
      }
    }
  },
  props: {
    test: String
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('check vue test', this.test)
  }
};
</script>
```

**Angular part**

> html

```
<section class="vue-dialog">
  <ng-container *ngIf="toVue">
    <my-vue-component test="{{ toVue.value }}"></my-vue-component>
  </ng-container>
</section>
```

> ComponentsModule

```
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
```

With the above steps, Vue's web component can be displayed correctly, but there is a big problem with passing data. If I use this method:

```
<my-vue-component test="angular data"></my-vue-component>
```

This can be successful because it's hardcoded. However, if I use any of the following methods, none of them work:

```
<my-vue-component test="{{ toVue.value }}"></my-vue-component>
<my-vue-component [attr.test]="toVue.value.toString()"></my-vue-component>
<my-vue-component [attr.test]="toVue.value | json"></my-vue-component>
```

In Vue log, it will always only display undefined. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks to everyone who helps!

Comment: did you try passing value like this ? ```[test]="toVue.value"```

Comment: Hi @NarayanDeshmukh I did it, but it not work :(